# when I include a library, I receive the following error System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net

An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred. After changing the target to x86, it is OK. I am wondering does it mean the library is 32 bit only. How to make it work with 64 bit too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library probably target to x86. Do you have source or it 3rd party? You need to recompile it to AnyCPU if it possible. You can try to use [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699.aspx) to change it to AnyCPU but it will works only if library not specifically intended to use in x86 only.

I put a bit info some time ago, maybe it will be helful: [Moving from 32-bit applications to 64-bit applications](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/moving-from-32-bit-applications-to-64-bit-applications-en/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley you cannot mix 64bit and 32 bit native (unmanaged) code together.
i had the same problem with the dotnet-Sqlite-assembly that contains native code.

> After changing the target to x86, it is OK.

That is an indicator that your program uses a library/dll that has some x86-native code. if you have that library compiled for 64bit and copy it to your 64bit-bin directory than your program might rund under 64 bit. (at least that works with my sqlite-problem)